# Removing many to many associations in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a many to many relationship using NHibernate.

Is there an easier way of removing the category association from all products without creating an class for the Join Table?

I'd like the SQL to look like

```
DELETE FROM ProductCategories WHERE CategoryId = 123
```

and here's the code we're using to delete the associations

```
        DetachedCriteria fetchCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Product>()
            .CreateAlias("Categories", "categories")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("categories.Id", category.Id));

        ICollection<Product> products = productRepo.FindAll(fetchCriteria);

        foreach(var product in products)
        {
            product.Categories.Remove(category);
            productRepo.Save(product);
        }
```

A Product has a set of Categories

```
public class Product{
    public ISet<Category> Categories
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

A Category has an Id Guid property

```
public class Category {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Many thanks :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the `ISession.Delete(query)` method? It takes a HQL query, loads the objects then deletes them.

```
session.Delete("from Product p join p.Categories c where c.id = :category", category, NHibernateUtil.Entity(typeof(Category)));
```

My HQL is a but rusty, so excuse me if the query is not quite right.

Another option if you're not keen on the idea of preloading all the objects, is to use `session.CreateSQLQuery` and just pass in a straight SQL statement to do the delete. NHibernate will execute that against the server no questions asked.